# OpenWRT: How can I kick a wireless client from command-line?

Tags: wireless-networking, openwrt

I understand for **"kicking"** a **momentary (temporary) disconnection** of a specific associated wireless client.

It is not the same as **"banning"**, that includes some sort of permanent **black-listing** of such client.

How could this kicking of a specific wireless associated client be obtained by  using command-line methods?

Comment: ban, and release the ban (if you happen to have a script to ban)? Because my understanding is - even if you kick the client - the client will simply attempt to rejoin to the wireless. If you ban for 1 minute or so, Windows client usually "give up" and make it into a manual connection - unless you don't want that to happen?

Comment: Indeed, @Darius : ban and quickly release the ban could be a valid method. If there is no valid answer here, trying at StackOverflow could be a good idea. Thanks you.

Answer (score 3):

UPDATE: simplifying informations thanks to comments from @pim

The best method to retrieve association informations for eg on card wlan1 should be the command `iwinfo wlan1 assoclist` that can be installed with `opkg install iwinfo`, or with modern drivers: `iw dev wlan1 station dump` . Anyway the "kick" method here (disassociate) is supported only if the hardware is supported with hostapd (Provided by default by the combo package [wpad-mini](https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/wireless.utilities) on OpenWRT)

The default `wpad-mini` package does provide the `disassociate` command but not the `all_sta`. So get the list of associated clients on card `wlan1` with `iwinfo wlan1 assoclist`, select a MAC address and then "kick" it with (for example):

```
hostapd_cli disassociate -i wlan1 01:23:45:67:89:AB
```

Considering a client usually tries to reconnect when disconnected, this might just disconnect it for about 10s.

Comment: Excuse me, but what do you mean for "tested with actual Wireless"? Some Linux distro acting as access point, maybe?

Comment: I just tested it on openwrt (lede 17.01.4). The all_sta command is not working, but the disassociate is working. This is probably because the default install use wpad-mini and not the full-featured hostapd package.

Comment: @pim Ok. So it's a bit more difficult to know what to disassociate. How do you do it? logs ?

Comment: To get a list of connected clients : `iwinfo wlan1 assoclist` (`iwinfo` must be installed first (`opkg install iwinfo`)) or `iw dev wlan1 station dump`. And don't forget to use the same interface for the disassociate command, example : `hostapd_cli disassociate -i wlan1 01:23:45:67:89:AB
`